# Python : Why do new lines keep appearing after every value amend?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I'm trying various small things to see how they work:

```
items = dict()

with open(path) as f:
   content = f.readlines()
   for line in content:
       splitStuff = line.split('!')
       if splitStuff[0] in item:
           items[splitStuff[0]] += ',' + Results[1]
       else:
           items[splitStuff[0]] = Results[1]
f.close()  

with open(path2, 'a') as f:
   for key, value in items.items():
       f.write(key + '!' + value)

f.close()
```

It opens a file with this content:

```
3!Angel
3!Devil
4!Nasko
4!Pesho
4!Gosho
5!Kalin
6!Gancho
6!Boncho
6!Toncho
6!Moncho
```

And ends up writing a file with this content:

```
3!Angel
,Devil
4!Nasko
,Pesho
,Gosho
5!Kalin
6!Gancho
,Boncho
,Toncho
,Moncho
```

The part I don't understand is where are those new lines appearing from every time I edit a value?

EDIT: This is the desired output.

```
3!Angel,Devil
4!Nasko,Pesho,Gosho
5!Kalin
6!Gancho,Boncho,Toncho,Moncho
```

**EDIT2: Never mind figured it out. Its because there are new lines in the original file and apparently reading file line by line catches them as well in python, unlike c# where they are ignored.**

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: Hi, I edited the main post to show the desired output.

Comment: The lines returned by `.readlines()` *include the newline character at the end*.  You need to remove that - `splitStuff = line.strip().split('!')` perhaps.  Note that you'll have to add your own newline after each line when you produce your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lines you read with `readlines()` have a trailing newline.

```
for line in content:
    line = line.rstrip()   
    splitStuff = line.split('!')
    ... etc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution could look like this:

```
path = "file1"
path2 = "file2"

items = dict()

with open(path) as f:
   content = f.readlines()
   for line in content:
       splitStuff = line.split('!')
       if splitStuff[0] in items:
           items[splitStuff[0]] += ',' + splitStuff[1][:-1]
       else:
           items[splitStuff[0]] = splitStuff[1][:-1]
f.close()

with open(path2, 'a') as f:
   for key, value in items.items():
       f.write(key + '!' + value)
       f.write("\n")

f.close()
```

You just had to remove the newline from each line of the file by adding `[:-1]`.

Comment: Good to know that there are multiple ways around this. Thanks.